# Image Data from URL in Typescript

Tags: typescript, canvas

I am trying to get `imageData` from an `image url` in typescript. I know the basic way is to create a canvas and use `drawImgae()` method of context. But in my case as I am using typescript I am not really working with a DOM tree. I am working with npm package.

I tried creating canvas and the `drawImage()` method of context. But while running test cases I got error saying `Image() is not defined`